# "SHIMVIEW:Shiminfo(complete)" message when i compile an app in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-8.1

When I use qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-mingw and my OS is Window 8.1,every time I compile a new project I've just created,the compiler shows me the message SHIMVIEW:Shiminfo(complete),but the app runs perfectly.Can someone tell me what this message means?

Answer (score 4):

> This message means that (for whatever reason) Windows is applying
>   compatibility shim to your app

[source](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/41315)